# How to change order of commits when interactive rebasing in bash (OSX)

Tags: bash, git, macos, rebase

I need to perform an interactive rebase so I can change the order of some of my commits, but I am unsure how to do this with bash on OSX.

Is this possible? I can change the action like `pick` to something else, but how can I physically move the commit lines around?

Comment: Just move the whole line to the desired place.

Comment: forgive me, I am fairly new to bash, how do i do the move? I cannot cut and paste the lines in bash

Comment: What editor do you use?

Comment: Im using VSCode, so am just now looking into how I get that to be my default git editor!

Comment: Try setting the `$EDITOR` environment variable.

Comment: If you haven't set `EDITOR`, then the default is Vim (`vi`). You can delete the line with the cursor by pressing `d` twice and then move the cursor and press `P` to put it above the current line or `p` to put it below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+reorder+commits